# Rspec matched for chained methods

Tags: rspec

Is there a way to rewrite this spec?

```
      expect(subject.root.name).to eq('DEMDataSet')
      expect(subject.root.elements[0].name).to eq('dAgency.Group')
      expect(subject.root.elements[0].elements[0].name).to eq('dAgency.02')
      expect(subject.root.elements[0].elements[1].name).to eq('dAgency.01')
```

I fill that the repetition of `subject.root` and the `subject.root.elements` can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming accessing the chains' results doesn't change across expectations, you can save the result in a regular Ruby variable within the `it` block, or you can use RSpec's `let` memoization helper as follows (not tested):

```
describe "..." do
  ...
  let(:root) { subject.root }
  let(:element0) { root.elements[0] }
  ....
  it "..." do
    ...
    expect(root.name).to eq('DEMDataSet')
    expect(element0.name).to eq('dAgency.Group')
    expect(element0.elements[0].name).to eq('dAgency.02')
    expect(element0.elements[1].name).to eq('dAgency.01')
    ...
  end
end
```

You could eliminate the remaining duplication in the `expect` arguments of the last two statements by defining a method which takes an integer and returns the names in question, but unless there are a lot of more of those, that probably doesn't increase readability. And of course, you could define your own method to eliminate the duplication of the `expect(...).to eq(...)` pattern itself, if you wanted to do so.

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution, I was hoping for something a little cooler like http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: Thank _you_ for pointing me to the blog, which I'd missed. I'll read it and see if I can apply it here so I can share something you didn't already know. ;-)